# How to set a radio button as default as make it hidden?

Tags: asp.net, forms, radio-button

i am totally a new in asp.net but for some reason, i have to change a little in the following code

```
<TR>
                <TD STYLE="WIDTH: 25%" ALIGN="RIGHT">I am:&nbsp;</TD>
                <TD STYLE="WIDTH: 75%" ALIGN="LEFT">
                     <INPUT TYPE="RADIO"  VALUE="Buy-New-Home" NAME="STATUS" ID="STATUS_BUYER" onClick="enableSection( 'Buyer' );"<% if( Request.QueryString( "STATUS" ) == "Buy-New-Home" || Request.QueryString( "STATUS" ).Count == 0 ) Response.Write( " CHECKED" ); %>>Buying
                    <INPUT TYPE="RADIO"  VALUE="Sell-Home" NAME="STATUS" ID="STATUS_SELLER" onClick="enableSection( 'Seller' );"<% if( Request.QueryString( "STATUS" ) == "Sell-Home" ) Response.Write( " CHECKED" ); %>>Selling           ---->>
                    <INPUT TYPE="RADIO"  VALUE="Buy-Resale-Home" NAME="STATUS" ID="STATUS_BOTH" onClick="enableSection( 'Both' );"<% if( Request.QueryString( "STATUS" ) == "Buy-Resale-Home" ) Response.Write( " CHECKED" ); %>>Both
                </TD>
```

How can i change the above code to

1: SELECT "BOTH" AS DEFUALT

2: MEANWHILE it is hidden, user will not click on it, and user will not be able to see it,

3: the form will submit the value of "both" to action script

(what i know, either a button is hidden or radio, so setting it radio and hidden might not be possible,)

Guide me Please..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you place it in a hidden div (or span), then you did not show it, but still exist and can be the default selected. And the value of it will be posted.

```
<div style="display:none;">
<INPUT TYPE="RADIO"  VALUE="Buy-Resale-Home" NAME="STATUS" ID="STATUS_BOTH" onClick="enableSection( 'Both' );"<% if( Request.QueryString( "STATUS" ) == "Buy-Resale-Home" ) Response.Write( " CHECKED" ); %>>Both
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this using Javascript and a regular ASP Radio Button List:

Javascript:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        var radios = document.getElementById('<%=list.ClientID%>').getElementsByTagName('input');
        for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
            if (radios[i].value == "Both" && '<%=Request.QueryString["Both"]=="Buy-Resale-Home" %>'.toLowerCase() == 'true') {
                radios[i].checked = 'checked'; //select it
                radios[i].style.display = 'none'; //hide it
            }
            else  //more logic for other 2 radio buttons
            {
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Markup:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="list" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Both" Value="Both"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Selling"  Value="Selling"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Buying"  Value="Buying"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

You could alternatively, do everything on code behind which is, in my opinion, better than this javascript approach but it would depend on which language you are most familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way of doing this is to not bother having a radio button for "Both". If it's hidden anyway and you never want the user to interact with it, then just don't put it on your page. Don't set either "Buyer" or "Seller" to selected (initially) so that the default is neither. This will allow you to check in your code behind if neither is selected like so...

In your markup:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList id="StatusRadioList" CssClass="radio-buttons" RepeatLayout="Flow" runat="server">
  <asp:ListItem>Buyer</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem>Seller</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

(notice that i am using RepeatLayout="Flow" - this tells asp.net to render the markup without using tables for the layout - much nicer i think)

In your code behind file you'll have a button click handler to respond to the user submitting the form - something like this:

```
protected void OnFormSubmitClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsValid)
    {
        string status;
        if (StatusRadioList.SelectedItem == null)
        {
            status = "Both";
        }
        else
        {
            status = StatusRadioList.SelectedValue;
        }

        // The rest of your code here
        // ...
    }
}
```

In the above example i have used the RadioButtonList's SelectedValue to get a string value for "status", but you could just as easily use the SelectedItem or SelectedIndex if that works better for you.

Also, if you wanted to shorten the code you could use a ternary instead of an if/else - Like so:

```
string status = (StatusRadioList.SelectedItem == null) 
                    ? "Both" 
                    : StatusRadioList.SelectedValue;
```